# How to detect open/closed and Drag an image by it Hand pointer using Microsoft Kinect v2

Tags: c#, kinect

In a Window 8 app, I want to drag an Image Using Kinect hand Pointer with Kinect V2.
I can Drag that image using Mouse pointer But Cannot with the Kinect hand pointer...

Could not Read the Grip state of hand pointer Please Help......

```
KinectCoreWindow kinectCoreWindow = KinectCoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread(); 
kinectCoreWindow.PointerMoved += kinectCoreWindow_PointerMoved;

private void kinectCoreWindow_PointerMoved(KinectCoreWindow sender,KinectPointerEventArgs args)
{
    KinectPointerPoint hand = args.CurrentPoint;

    var xpoint = hand.Position.X;
    var ypoint = hand.Position.Y;

    //txtxypoints.Text = "X :" + xpoint + "  Y : " + ypoint;

    txtxypoints.Text = "HandReachExtent : " + hand.Properties.HandReachExtent.ToString();
    txtxypoints2.Text = "HandRotation : " + hand.Properties.HandRotation.ToString();
    txtxypoints3.Text = "HandType : " + hand.Properties.HandType.ToString();
    txtxypoints4.Text = "IsEngaged : " + hand.Properties.IsEngaged.ToString();
    txtxypoints5.Text = "IsInRange : " + hand.Properties.IsInRange.ToString();
    txtxypoints6.Text = "IsPrimary : " + hand.Properties.IsPrimary.ToString();
    txtxypoints7.Text = "PressExtent : " + hand.Properties.PressExtent.ToString();
    txtxypoints8.Text = "BodyTimeCounter : " + hand.Properties.BodyTimeCounter.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Is "Could not read the grip state of hand pointer" an error you're getting?

Comment: No i Am Not getting an error